# Xcode Beta 4: Can't create a Bot - Crashes every time

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-bots, xcode7-beta4

Every time I try to create a bot with Xcode Beta 4, I get a crash.

```
Process:               Xcode [4678]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.0 (8178.7)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-8178007000000000~3
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [4678]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-07-22 10:42:20.647 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        ***


Time Awake Since Boot: 880 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7A165t
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): View     <NSPopUpButton: 0x7ffaf0480970> is not (and has to be) in stack view <NSStackView: 0x7ffaf0486080>.
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
```

This looks like the relevant bit and it seems like it's an Xcode bug.

`UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): View     <NSPopUpButton: 0x7ffaf0480970> is not (and has to be) in stack view <NSStackView: 0x7ffaf0486080>.`

Other people with the same issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily a fix, but a good workaround:

1. Open project in Xcode 7 beta 3 or Xcode 6
2. Switch Server to run with Xcode 7 beta 3 or Xcode 6
3. Create Bot using older version of Xcode
4. Switch Server to run with Xcode 7 beta 4
5. Bots seem to run fine using Xcode 7 beta 4 (you just can't create them)

I had to do this because my project is using iOS 9 and another bug made Xcode 7 beta 3 unable to run tests with bots.

Answer (score 1):

Submit a bug report... The more valid reports they receive the more quickly they can fix it.  Be sure to submit any work around so's they can communicate them, should they decide to do so.